# Load PDF in UIWebView and got error DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have loaded PDF in UIWebView

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ConferenceMap_2014" ofType:@"pdf"];

if (thePath) {

   NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

   [webViewPDF loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];

}
```

Error : DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.

Answer (score -1):

Hi download the class file from [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5JC34Lt79ctOUE1WVo5T2NmSVU).

then import the **"UIView+DocumentView.h"**

after that get the path of particular file

NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] **pathForResource:@"file1427464777.586564" ofType:@"pdf"];**

Next call the class with particular path
**[self.view makeDocumentView:thePath];**

Comment: That doesn't really explain what went wrong and how to properly fix it.